# Вставка текста из буфера в ватсап

Tags: c#, winforms

Не могли бы вы помочь со ставкой текста из буфера обмена в текстовое поле ватсап? (C#, Windows Forms, приложение) Заранее, очень благодарен! Этот решил проблему, (https://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread2733428.html#post15063577) но только в блокноте, а мне нужно чтобы текст вставлялся в ватсап из буфера...Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Что такое "ватсап", если у вас winforms а ватсап является веб-сайтом или мобильным приложением? Вот как вы себе это представляете и что у вас из этого уже готово?

Comment: "ватсап" - "WhatsApp.exe" по той ссылке показано, как можно ставить текст из буфера в блокнот, а мне нужно чтобы текст можно было вставить именно в приложение WhatsApp